# How to increase the size of the .ed_history file

Tags: command-history, readline, ed

I am running `GNU ed 1.18` on `Fedora Linux 36`. I run `ed` with `rlwrap` also installed which gives me access to my command history. My `.ed_history` file appears to have a size limit of 300 lines. I would like to increase that limit, perhaps to unlimited if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question about `rlwrap` ("readline wrapper") more than about `ed`.

The `rlwrap` tool has a default history size of 300 entries.  You may increase this by using the tool's `-s` (`--histsize`) option:

```bash
rlwrap -s 1000 ed
```

There is no way to set an "unlimited" history size.  Instead, pick a *large enough* number as the argument to `-s`.

You may also set the history size that `rlwrap` will use with `ed` by adding a section like the following to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
$if ed
        set history-size 1000
$endif
```